# Annotation for mapping Joda Time "Period" in JPA using Eclipse Link

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jodatime, period

I am having a field - `expiryLimit` in my `Item` entity for which I thought of using *joda-time* `Period` which would be an appropriate type to use here.

Just to explain - `expiryLimit` is the number of *year*, *month*, *days*, or any duration after which a particular *item* will expire and using which I can calculate the exact `expiryDate` of an `Item` given a `deliveryDate`.

Now the problem I'm facing is finding an appropriate way to map this type into `JPA`.

Is there any available *API* or *3rd party library* which provides some annotation to do that? Also I've used the *Eclipse Link* `@Converter` annotation to map `DateTime` with *MySQL* `TimeStamp`. So, would I need to do the same thing with `Period` also. And if yes, then to what type should I convert it. To `varchar`? or to `Long`? or some other type appropriate to represent a `Period`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, finally I've solved the issue by using *EclipseLink* `@Converter` only. This is how I've done it. I also welcome any comments on this way: -

### ItemMaster entity: -

```
public class ItemMaster {
    @Converter(
        name="periodConverter",
        converterClass = com.joda.converter.PeriodConverter.class
    )
    @Convert("periodConverter")
    @Column(name = "expiry_limit", length = 2000)
    private Period expiryLimit;

    /** Constructors **/


    public Period getExpiryLimit() {
        return expiryLimit;
    }

    public void setExpiryLimit(Period expiryLimit) {
        this.expiryLimit = expiryLimit;
    }
}
```

### PeriodConverter.class: -

```
public class PeriodConverter implements Converter {

    private Logger log;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object str, Session session) {
        if (str == null) {
            log.info("convertDataValueToObjectValue returning null");
            return null;
        }
        return new Period(str);

    }

    @Override
    public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object period, Session session) {
        /** str format should be: - `PyYmMwWdDThHmMsS` **/
        if (period == null) {
            log.info("convertObjectValueToDataValue returning null");
            return null;
        }
        return period.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {
        log = Logger.getLogger("com.joda.converter.PeriodConverter");
        ((AbstractDirectMapping) mapping).setFieldType(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```