# Jodatime Period to Jadira Usertype PersistentPeriodAsString. Giving custom format?

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, period, usertype

I need to store delta time I'm receiving in the format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm` in database. For that I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class. Now, I've to do the mapping from `Period` to DB column. I'm using Hibernate Framework, and found out [Jadira `UserType` project](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html). Sounds good. Here's what I've got till now:

```
@Entity
class SomeEntity {
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentPeriodAsString")
    private Period deltaTime;
}
```

But the issue is, it has a specific format - `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`, as I guess it uses [`AbstractPeriod#toString()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPeriod.html#toString%28%29) method.

How can I alter it to use the one argument [`AbstractPeriod#toString(PeriodFormatter)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPeriod.html#toString%28org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter%29) passing my own PeriodFormatter, to store it in the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm` format?

Earlier I faced this issue with JPA and EclipseLink, and [I solved it using EclipseLink Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208624/annotation-for-mapping-joda-time-period-in-jpa-using-eclipse-link), but haven't found a way till yet to resolve this. Any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own type. To do that, you can mirror the definition of `PersistentPeriodAsString` by extending `AbstractSingleColumnUserType` and providing your own `ColumnMapper`:

```
public class PersistentPeriodAsFormattedString extends
        AbstractSingleColumnUserType<Period, String,
            StringColumnPeriodFormatterMapper> {
}

public class StringColumnPeriodFormatterMapper extends
        AbstractStringColumnMapper<Period> {
    private static final PeriodFormatter FORMATTER = ...;

    @Override
    public Period fromNonNullValue(String s) {
        return FORMATTER.parsePeriod(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String toNonNullValue(Period value) {
        return value.toString(FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

Note that for any `UserType` the following must be true ([Hibernate Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html)):

```
Implementors must be immutable and must declare a public default constructor.
```

Similarly, the `ColumnMapper` used by `AbstractSingleColumnUserType` must define a public default constructor as [an instance is instantiated by reflections](https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/blob/master/usertype.spi/src/main/java/org/jadira/usertype/spi/shared/AbstractSingleColumnUserType.java#L41):

```
columnMapper = (C) TypeHelper
    .getTypeArguments(AbstractSingleColumnUserType.class, getClass()).get(2)
    .newInstance();
```

Comment: Bang on!! This is the way to go. Thanks :)